# writing your own local planner? Template?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all

I want to write my own local planner to used with the navigation stack.
I already have written my code; what is left is to modify it so it could be used with the navigation stack.  I am wondering, is there a template or any guidance for writing your own local planner?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/73228/writing-your-own-local-planner?-template?/) by [Gazer](https://answers.ros.org/users/4846/gazer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 146 on 2013-08-15

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The template is the BaseLocalPlanner interface class. You'll need to make that into a plugin and that should be it.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2013-08-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [M_wasiel13](https://answers.ros.org/users/26602/m_wasiel13/) on 2016-10-26**:
Hello Could you be more precisly? I  clone repository from https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation.. Is there any tutorial how to edit base_local_planner and implement own planner.
Best regards
Mateusz Wasielewski